# Как из кортежа получить словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как из кортежа new_letter получить словарь?

```py
letters = {'а': 1, 'б': 2}
name = str.casefold(input("Введите запрос:"))
for i, letter in enumerate(name):
    if letter in letters.keys():
        new_letter = (letter, letters[letter])
```

Comment: покажите пример ввода и желаемый результат к нему

Comment: letters = {'а': 1, 'б': 2...}
name = str.casefold(input("Введите запрос:"))
for i, letter in enumerate(name):
    if letter in letters.keys():
        new_letter = (letter, letters[letter])                                                                                       
   Введите запрос:Петр
('п', 8)
('е', 6)
('т', 2)
('р', 9) дальше хочу полученные кортежи закинуть в один словарь буква ключ, цифра значение

Comment: а если слово аа? в словаре не может быть два одинаковых ключа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

напишите вот так

```py
....
    if letter in letters.keys():
        # new_letter = (letter, letters[letter])
        new_letter[letter] = letters[letter]
```

Сразу записывайте в словарь. Ну, и объявить не забудьте.